# Pony ORM - tear down in testing

Tags: python, pytest, ponyorm

I am using Pony ORM for managing an sqlite database in a python package I am developing.

I would like to use pytest for testing.

My package provides an "agent" object, which is used to connect to a server API and retrieve "events". On initialisation of the agent, the pony orm is setup and bound to a sqlite db, either in memory (for testing) or as a file.

```py
    def setup_db(filepath=None):
        if filepath:
            db.bind(provider="sqlite", filename=filepath, create_db=True)
        else:
            db.bind(provider="sqlite", filename=":memory:", create_db=True)
        db.provider.converter_classes.append((Enum, EnumConverter))
        db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

The state of the events are stored in an sqlite db using pony orm.

I wish to create a new agent object, with a clean database for each test, so I am using a pytest fixture in the `conftest.py` file.

```py
    @pytest.fixture
    def agent():
        agent=Agent(parm1="param1",...)
        return agent
```

I am unable to correctly "unbind" from the database and get this error on my second test:

`pony.orm.core.BindingError: Database object was already bound to SQLite 
provider`

I would like some advice on the best way to proceed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think for your case you should make some factory for entities and create new db objects for each setup.

```
def define_entities(db):
    class Student(db.Entity):
        ...

    class Group(db.Entity):
        ...
```

So then you can do something like

```
def setup_db(filepath=None):
    db = Database()
    if filepath:
        db.bind(provider="sqlite", filename=filepath, create_db=True)
    else:
        db.bind(provider="sqlite", filename=":memory:", create_db=True)
    define_entities(db)
    db.provider.converter_classes.append((Enum, EnumConverter))
    db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if I do this I am unable to reference the models in other parts of the code, I'm likely missing something?

Comment: @peteretep all entities are available from `db.entities`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Pony code it seems it should be enough to clear `provider` attribute of `Database` instance to make it *fresh* so it can be bind again.

If you yield `Agent` instead of returning it from your fixture, everything you put after `yield` statement will be run as fixture tear down code.

Comment: You also need to clear `schema`. `db.provider = db.schema = None` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [previous answer from zgoda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271460/266362) almost works. Besides `db.provider`, it is also necessary to clear `db.schema`. My suggestion is that you create another function:

```py
def unbind_db():
    db.provider = db.schema = None
```

And your fixture should be something like:

```py
@fixture
def database() -> None:
    setup_db()
    ...
    try:
       yield
    finally:
       unbind_db()
```